how to collecting trace data without using SDK?
Goal:
I want to collect Log, Metric, and Trace data obtained through OpenTelemetry from an application without modifying the code within the application, similar to how Dynatrace's oneagent works.
I know that collecting Logs and Metrics is possible using Loki or Prometheus. However, it seems impossible to collect Trace data in the same way. If there is a way to do this, please let me know.
